# Как затемнить картинку в header?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь затемнить header так, что бы nav остался со своим цветом, т.е. не затемнялся, а весь блок с картинкой затемнялся. Но чё-то не выходит, помогите советом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
`<header id="header" class="header">        
        <nav class="header-nav">
            <ul class="header-nav_links">
                <li>Contacts</li>
                <li>Skills</li>
                <li>Experience</li>
            </ul>           
        </nav>
</header>`
```

Хочу что бы было вот так, но nav был не `position: absolute;`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И как нам догадаться, что вы делаете? Добавьте хотя бы стили, а лучше рабочий пример.

Comment: исправил, смотрите)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте код или хотя бы стили для получения точного ответа.

Вы можете использовать свойство opacity:

```
#header {
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Подробно читайте: http://htmlbook.ru/css/opacity

Или rgba:

```
#header {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* Белый с 50% альфа-каналом */
}


#header {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Чёрный с непрозрачностью 50% */
}
```

Подробно можете читать и посмотреть пример тут: https://frontender.info/the-power-of-rgba/

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из вашей разметки

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.header-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.header-nav_links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header-nav_links>li {
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header">
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <ul class="header-nav_links">
      <li>Contacts</li>
      <li>Skills</li>
      <li>Experience</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```